# Symfony - two forms activate separately

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I wrote a function that has two forms that are activate separately, persisting same Entity. First is activated for input field and second for random generated field.

But when I click submit it activates both forms one after other. If used conditions to prevent that but I seems that it doesn't work.

My code:

```
     $id = $request->get('id');

    $user = $this->container->get('account')->getUserRepository()->find($id);

    $form1 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Enter New Password',
        'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Send', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save']
    ))
    ->getForm();

    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Generate New Password',
        'disabled'=> true,
        'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Send',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save']
    ))
    ->getForm();

    $form1->handleRequest($request);
    if($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {

        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'You successfully changed the password!'
        );

        $data = $form1->getData();

        $new_password = $data['password'];

        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
        $new_pwd_encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($new_password);

        $oneTimePsw = '';
        $user->setPassword($new_pwd_encoded);
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $manager->flush();
    }

    $form2->handleRequest($request);
    if($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {

        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Password is successfully generated!'
        );

        $data = $form2->getData();

        $new_password = $data['password'];);

        $new = $this->get('member.account')->generateRandomPassword();

        $oneTimePsw = '';
        $user->setPassword($new);
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $manager->flush();
    }
return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/admin/reset_password.html.twig', array(
        'form1' => $form1->createView(),
        'form2' => $form2->createView()
    ));

My twig

    <div id="setPassword" style="display:none;">
    {{ form_start(form1) }}

    {{ form_end(form1) }}
</div>

<div id="generatePassword" style="display:none;">
    {{ form_start(form2) }}

    {{ form_end(form2) }}
</div>
```

Comment: pls post your ```reset_password.html.twig``` file. You may have nested both forms inside each other, such that while submitting one form, the other is triggered too.

Comment: Updated. I think the tamplate is okey. @MaximilianKaske

Comment: okay, take a look in your web inspector if the two forms have different names. It seems to me that both forms have identical form names. If so, submitting one will automatically submit the other.

Comment: @MaximilianKaske I think it is the form's id instead name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a simple if else anidation problem, when i had the same issue this is what i did:

```
$id = $request->get('id');

$user = $this->container->get('account')->getUserRepository()->find($id);

$form1 = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Enter New Password',
    'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Send', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save']
))
->getForm();

$form2 = $this->createFormBuilder()
->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Generate New Password',
    'disabled'=> true,
    'attr' => ['class'=>'form-control']))
->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Send',
    'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-primary action-save']
))
->getForm();
$form1->handleRequest($request);
$form2->handleRequest($request);
if($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) {

    $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'You successfully changed the password!'
    );

    $data = $form1->getData();

    $new_password = $data['password'];

    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);
    $new_pwd_encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($new_password);

    $oneTimePsw = '';
    $user->setPassword($new_pwd_encoded);
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $manager->flush();
}else

    if($form2->isSubmitted() && $form2->isValid()) {

    $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'Password is successfully generated!'
    );

    $data = $form2->getData();

    $new_password = $data['password'];);

    $new = $this->get('member.account')->generateRandomPassword();

    $oneTimePsw = '';
    $user->setPassword($new);
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $manager->flush();
}
return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/admin/reset_password.html.twig', array(
    'form1' => $form1->createView(),
    'form2' => $form2->createView()
));
```

This should work, because a user can't submit 2 forms at once. I also had a problem with the isValid() method so also try for testing taking it down.